# How to get Location names in Android google map v2 under radius of 100 kilometer

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude, google-places-api

I want to get all the location name under the radius circle of 100 kilometer from my current location like shown in the image below. I am using android Google map API v2. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: use google places api make a request with params like radius 100km and what all location you want like food places hospitals and so on. read google places api docs

Comment: Something like this https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&sensor=false&key=yourkey. You will get a json response parse it and then display it in a way you want.

Comment: I want to get city names under that circle(radius).

Comment: Ok thanks i will read the docs

Comment: and read https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types. Quoting **the (cities) type collection instructs the Places service to return results that match locality or administrative_area_level_3**

Comment: can you refer some source for study ....... that you think its helpful

Comment: thanks i got your link